# Create stored procedure to query a table that does not yet exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

As the title says, I need to make a stored procedure that will create a temp table, query that temp table, and return a column from it. The problem is that in order to populate the temp table, I need to pass in a parameter which the user will declare at runtime. Here's the code I've been trying:

```
USE GameDayReporting;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetPercentOfSection @EventID nvarchar(50)
AS 
SELECT * INTO #temp
    FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;' 
   ,'set fmtonly off exec GameDayReporting.dbo.uspGetEventKillSheetDetailedReport @EventID') 


SELECT PctCap FROM #temp

GO
```

`PctCap` is a column in `uspGetEventKillSheetDetailedReport`, but SQL doesn't recognize it because the temp table isn't being created, because I have no user input for `EventID`.

We thought of initializing `EventID` at 0, but I believe when we actually pass in a valid `EventID` it will just be overwritten to 0 before creating the temp table.

Get ready for a very horribly worded question (I have no idea how to ask this any other way haha):

How should I rewrite this Stored Procedure to create a temp table from the results of a separate Stored Procedure which needs a parameter that I do not have yet?

Error messages:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@EventID".
```

Comment: You need to create temp table in advance (their lifecycle is per-session/connection).Eventually you should drop it (if exists) before you try to create it.

Comment: @rkosegi For now I just need to create the procedure in general, though I did overlook dropping the temp table first so thank you for that. What do you mean I need to create the temp table first?

Comment: It will only use the default 0 if nothing is passed in.  Otherwise if you pass a valid EventID all will be well and you will have a correctly passed EventID not 0.  Default values in sql are there for default empty or unassigned values not when you actually pass in a valid value.

Comment: Why OPENROWSET, and not just regular dynamic SQL.

Comment: if this is a procedure, and you aren't going to take in a parameter for EventID, what is it's purpose?

Comment: @scsimon This code is just to create the SP `uspGetPercentOfSection` with the `EventID` parameter. Eventually I'm going to call it from my MVC Controller with the `EventID` parameter being entered by the user

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I'm admittedly not entirely familiar with this, `OPENROWSET` was just the first piece I came across

Comment: Then just create it as `CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetPercentOfSection @EventID nvarchar(50) = NULL` and you should be fine.

Comment: @scsimon `Must declare the scalar variable "@EventID".` still

Comment: Well you have to concat it into the openrow set just like Long described below

Comment: @scsimon I was eventually able to execute the command and create the procedure, however now SQL can't find the temp table I'm trying to create even when I enter an `EventID`

Answer (score 1):

`OPENROWSET` doesn't deal with variables, you need to use dynamic SQL and also parse your input variable.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max)
SET @SQL = 
'SELECT * INTO #temp
        FROM OPENROWSET (''SQLOLEDB'',''Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'' 
       ,''set fmtonly off exec GameDayReporting.dbo.uspGetEventKillSheetDetailedReport @EventID =''' + @EventID + ''')'

PRINT @SQL
--EXEC (SQL)
```

**UPDATE:**

I am guessing this is the issue with `scope`, what you could do instead is:

create `#temp` first, then use `insert into #temp` instead of `SELECT INTO #temp`, worth a try

OR

Use `global temporary tables`, such as `##temp`

**2nd UPDATE:**

Since you are creating `#temp` first, now you need to :

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max)
SET @SQL = 
'INSERT INTO #temp
        FROM OPENROWSET (''SQLOLEDB'',''Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'' 
       ,''set fmtonly off exec GameDayReporting.dbo.uspGetEventKillSheetDetailedReport @EventID =''' + @EventID + ''')'

--PRINT @SQL   
EXEC (SQL) --comment this line in if that @SQL is valid
```

Comment: Now SQL doesn't recognize that a temp table exists at all. Before it would acknowledge #temp's existence, but `PctCap` was not available

Comment: One moment... I was able to execute the command but the SP isn't showing up in my Object Explorer. Let me restart the program

Comment: Ok the procedure is created, however I cannot access the temp table still. Upon manually entering a valid EventId I get the error `Invalid object name '#temp'.`

Comment: As rkosegi said, temp table must be created BEFORE insert to it, temp table created within dynamic SQL dies alone with the dynamic code and is not visible in outer code at all

Comment: @sepupic, thanks, I just noticed that `#temp` might not exist anymore after `exec`

Comment: To be precise, not "might not exist", but for sure does not exist after dynamic code finishes

Comment: Hmm. Created the temp table first, added all the columns of the table I'm querying, then ran your dynamic SQL code and It's returning 0 for the `SELECT` return value

Comment: now you cannot use `select * into`, instead, need to be `insert into #temp`  and comment `EXEC(SQL)` in not leave it as commented out